# Frame Extraction at Fixed FPS Value

Tags: python, opencv

While extracting frames from a video using OpenCV, how can I set a particular value at which the frame extraction will occur?

I have seen many available sample codes for image extraction, but they are not shown any option for the frame rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of frame extraction, one is to use ffmg for frame extraction.

other is, You can try this code, but we can't use any random value that you will understand while trying at different values.
*change directories ap per your system*.

```
import math
count = 0
videoFile = "train/train.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)  
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
x=1
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(1) 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    else (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename ="train/frame2/frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
print ("Done!")
```

Comment: for ffmg do we need to use any software kind of thing?

Comment: I don't have much idea about ffmg, while going through one of my projects I got to know ffmg, and while processing it asked for some installation and I think we need to config it first.

Comment: Ya same here, it starts to give error and require some installation. Thanks